# How to configure AWS Cognito authentication in Apache Superset?

Tags: amazon-cognito, apache-superset

I'm trying to set up ***AWS Cognito*** with ***Apache Superset***

I'm using the following code in `superset_config.py`:

```py
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH

# Set the authentication type to OAuth
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
SECRET_KEY = '#########################'


OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {   'name':'awscognito',
        #'whitelist': [],
        'token_key':'access_token', # Name of the token in the response of access_token_url
        'enable_sso': True,
        'icon':'fa-amazon',   # Icon for the provider
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id':'########################',  # Client Id (Identify Superset application)
            'client_secret':'########', # Secret for this Client Id (Identify Superset application)
            #'token_key': 'access_token',
            'client_kwargs':{
                'scope': 'openid profile email'               # Scope for the Authorization
            },
            'access_token_method':'POST',    # HTTP Method to call access_token_url
            'access_token_params':{        # Additional parameters for calls to access_token_url
                'client_id':'##########'
            },
            'access_token_headers':{    # Additional headers for calls to access_token_url
                'Authorization': '###############'
            },
            "request_token_url": None,
            'api_base_url':'https://########.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/',
            #'access_token_url':'https://########.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',
            #'authorize_url':'https://########.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize'
            'authorize_url': 'https://########.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=########&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https>
            'access_token_url': "https://########.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=######&client_secret=######&Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }
]

# Map Authlib roles to superset roles
AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Public'
# Will allow user self registration, allowing to create Flask users from Authorized User
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Gamma'

from custom_sso_security_manager import CustomSsoSecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager
```

I'm using the following code in `custom_sso_security_manager.py`:

```py
import logging
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager

#from custom_sso_security_manager import CustomSsoSecurityManager
import jwt

class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        logging.debug(provider)
        if provider == "awscognito":
            logging.debug("PROVIDER-IS-COGNITO")
            id_token = response["id_token"]
            access_token = response["code"]
            userInfo = jwt.decode(access_token, verify=False)
            groups   = userInfo["cognito:groups"]
            userName = userInfo["cognito:username"]
            fullName = userInfo["name"]
            email    = userInfo["email"]
            logger.debug(email)
            logger.debug(userName)
            return {
                'fullname' : fullName,
                'email' : email,
                'username' : userName,
                'first_name':'',
                'last_name':''
                }
        else:
            return {}

#CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager
```

The first step of auth is working fine. However, I'm seeing this error in Superset:

> The request to sign in was denied.

and in logs it shows

> 2023-06-11 21:15:41,726:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new
> HTTPS connection (1):
> superset-test.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com:443 2023-06-11
> 21:15:41,979:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://#####.amazoncognito.com:443
> "POST
> /oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=#####&client_secret=####&Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' HTTP/1.1" 400 None 2023-06-11
> 21:15:41,983:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.views:Error authorizing
> OAuth access token: unsupported_grant_type:
> 172.20.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2023:21:15:41 +0000] "GET /oauth-authorized/awscognito?code=######&state=####

The expected result will be successful authentication of Superset using AWS Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Cognito. Go to app integration and select app that you have created. Edit the allowed host data. There you will get OAuth 2.0 grant types. Change to accept the appropriate grant types. If not sure then select both as I provided in the attached image below. This should solve your problem

[Attached Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Doffb.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).